# Why does npm(and programs in general) have deprecate issue even when installed from official website?

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby

I downloaded nodejs from its official website, and npm with it.

When I tried to run Gatsby:

```
npm install --save gatsby

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
```

...and so on

I can reinstall them one by one. But it makes me wonder why official website installation gives deprecated warnings. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with npm or node.js. Apparently the `gatsby` package that you are downloading does use some (transitive) dependencies that are deprecated.

Comment: I think this is telling you that the gatsby module you're trying to install is using some other modules that have been deprecated and will actually break on node v14+.  This is an issue with the gatsby module, not with node.js or npm.  You need to find out if the maintainers of the gatsby module are aware of this and working on fixing this or not.  If not, then you probably shouldn't be using this module unless you want to take responsibility  for fixing it yourself and maintaining it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there something I'm missing?

Let me turn the question around: can *you* 100% guarantee that for every project you have ever published, every dependency of your project is up-to-date, every dependency of every dependency of your project is up-to-date, every dependency of every dependency of every dependency of every project is up-to-date, and so on, and so forth?

I know I can't! In fact, I *know* that some of my projects have dependencies that in turn have dependencies that are no longer maintained. The problem is simply that I do those projects in my free time and re-designing the project to use a different dependency would take too much time that I don't have. I even know that some of my projects have dependencies that have unfixed security holes! But, the version which fixes that security hole has a backwards-incompatible API change, and I simply don't have the time to do the necessary re-write.

Remember that most of those projects are open source community projects, so, as a member of the community, it is in some sense even *your* job to fix those issues.

Gatsby has 85 direct dependencies. The transitive closure of dependencies, i.e. the set of Gatsby's dependencies, the dependencies of those dependencies, the dependencies of the dependencies of those dependencies, and so on, is 787 packages. Now, isn't it possible that the developers of Gatsby simply don't have time to constantly track every single one of those 787 packages to make sure that every single one is up-to-date?

Comment: Thank you for answer. What would be best way to solve this problem? Search stackoverflow for each line of deprecate warnings, or just ignore them? Seems nightmare to fix one by one.